# Magento 2 : on tab click ko js and template render

Tags: magento2, knockout

In my module, there are tab structure same like mentioned in this below image tab structure. I want to do like that, when on tab click at that time, ko template and ko js should be render.

How to do that ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]